# Cookie (un)serialization in Laravel 5.5.42

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Security release 5.5.42 "disables all serialization / unserialization of cookie values" - https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-30
But I have my values serialized still, only not unserialized. While I do

```
Cookie::get('key')
```

I get something like

```
"s:5:"value";"
```

Setting `protected static $serialize = true;` in App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies helps, and so does

```
unserialize(Cookie::get('key'))
```

But as I understand unserialize() itself is the source of the problem with this security release, not what I do with the unserialized value later, so this kinda beats the purpose of the update. 
Why are my cookies serialized here and how to fix this?

Comment: Cookies are encrypted so if you just regenerate your `APP_KEY`  then all old cookies will be invalidated and new ones will not be serialized. Yes this means that all encrypted values you generated will be invalid as well so you might need to re-encrypt those using the new key

Comment: Regenerating APP_KEY doesn't help. This happens also in my tests, both locally and in Bitbucket pipeline, where the key is generated each time and there's no cookie persistence.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually worth an answer as the question itself is quite interesting.

From a Laravel perspective this isn't a cookie problem as much as it's a `APP_KEY` config key problem combined with serialize/unserialize.

Relevant quote from the docs:

> However, if your application's encryption key is in the hands of a
>   malicious party, that party could craft cookie values using the
>   encryption key and exploit vulnerabilities inherent to PHP object
>   serialization / unserialization, such as calling arbitrary class
>   methods within your application.

The relevant part is this `vulnerabilities inherent to PHP object serialization / unserialization`.

Usually the form of explot is Object Injection(the most common at least).

OWASP has a very good example [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection).

Even php.net has a red warning [for it's unserliaze function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).

`Warning
Do not pass untrusted user input to unserialize()`

Cookies come from a user and users are NOT to be trusted.

Since an example is in order I'll just leave the OWASP one here too:

```
class Example1
{
   public $cache_file;

   function __construct()
   {
      // some PHP code...
   }

   function __destruct()
   {
      $file = "/var/www/cache/tmp/{$this->cache_file}";
      if (file_exists($file)) @unlink($file);
   }
}

// some PHP code...

$user_data = unserialize($_GET['data']);

// some PHP code...
```

In this example an attacker might be able to delete an arbitrary file via a Path [Traversal attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal), for e.g. requesting the following URL:

```
http://testsite.com/vuln.php?data=O:8:"Example1":1:{s:10:"cache_file";s:15:"../../index.php";}
```

---

With that said, I highly recommend reading(even briefly) about serialize/unserliaze vulnerabilities.

If you're using a proper framework, usually, you'll have most security things taken care of IF you don't go out of your way to introduce some vulnerability and you stick to the framework's standards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
That's why I don't want to use any of the 2 methods I mentioned (calling unserialize manually or setting the flag). But the value in cookie is still serialized. Should I just parse this myself?

Comment: Just chance your `APP_KEY` and you'll be fine. And ofc make sure nobody has access to it.

Comment: My test pipeline has php artisan key:generate in each run. I tried it locally as well. Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It's less efficient but in case of structured data, I replace serialize/unserialize with json_encode/json_decode.